# Match Multi line Events Using Only Starting Value

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm attempting to match events where the only way to tell when an event starts and ends is with the header or first value in the multi line event (e.g. START--). Basically, using the header as an ending anchor to get the whole event. Also, the last event will end at the end of the file, so there's no anchor for that one. I'm not quite sure how to make this work.

**Event Example** (There's no spaces between the lines)

```
START--random stuff here 
more random stuff on this new line 
more stuff and things 
START--some random things 
additional random things 
blah blah 
START--data data more data 
START--things 
blah data
```

```
$FileContent | select-string '^START--(.*?)^START--' -AllMatches | Foreach {$_.Matches} | Foreach {$_.Value}
```

Comment: Use `-Raw` when reading in the file. Then use `(?m)^START--(.*?)(?=\r?\nSTART--|\z)` regex (or `(?m)(?<=^START--).*?(?=\r?\nSTART--|\z)`)

Comment: if you use `-Raw` to load the file as  one multiline string, and then use `-split` to split on the `START--` ... you will have all your data blocks in an array as such. then you can process the blocks as needed.

Comment: Or `-split` with `(?m)^(?!\A)(?=START--)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may read in the file into a single variable (it can be done by passing `-Raw` option to `Get-Content`, for example) and split it at the start of lines starting with `START--` but the first line:

```
$contents = Get-Content 'your_file_path' -Raw
$contents -split '(?m)^(?!\A)(?=START--)'
```

It [will yield](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%3F!%5CA%29%28%3F%3DSTART--%29&i=START--random%20stuff%20here%0D%0Amore%20random%20stuff%20on%20this%20new%20line%0D%0Amore%20stuff%20and%20things%0D%0ASTART--some%20random%20things%0D%0Aadditional%20random%20things%20blah%20blah%0D%0ASTART--data%20data%20more%20data%0D%0ASTART--things%0D%0Ablah%20data)

[image]

**Regex details**

- `(?m)` - the multiline option is ON
- `^` - now, it matches start of lines due to `(?m)`
- `(?!\A)` - not the start of the whole string/text
- `(?=START--)` - the location that is immediately followed with `START--` substring.

Comment: How can I access each event? Tried putting it in a variable, but it comes back as one value.

Comment: @MrMr No, it is not one value. What do you need to do exactly with these records?

Comment: I'm trying to access each event it finds individually.

Comment: Sorry, never mind, I see what I did wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Also, will this capture the last event in the file if there isn't a START-- followed by it?

Comment: @MrMr It will, you can see it in the regex demo. Also, just if you do not need `TEST--` in the results, replace the lookahead with a consuming pattern, `'(?m)^(?!\A)START--'`

Comment: Just confirmed, thank you again. This was crazy fast, you rock.