# Least Expensive and Fastest Way to Read Large Text Files with Multi line Events

Tags: .net, powershell, text

I'm attempting to read very large text files (~1.5-2GB's) that have multi line events, like so:

```
START--random stuff here 
more random stuff on this new line 
more stuff and things 
START--some random things 
additional random things 
blah blah 
START--data data more data 
START--things 
blah data
```

... but in a *fast* and *non resource intensive* way. I'm not sure if this approach is the right one, but it still seems to take a while and I'm having trouble splitting the events properly, the results appear to be each line. Also, each step takes quite a while to complete and I'm wondering if I could do each of them in just one?

I'm building off of [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57417368/match-multi-line-events-using-only-starting-value/57417611?noredirect=1#comment101315083_57417611)

```
$NewContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('E:\Scripts\Logs\First1000')
$global:results = $NewContent -split '(?m)^(?!\A)(?=START--)'
```

Comment: To what end? What are you trying to do with the content of this "large text file"?

Comment: I plan to send the events found out VIA syslog. I have a function ready to go for that.

Comment: By "found out" do you mean every event/line encountered or do you want to filter each line and if the filter matches then "send it"?

Comment: The end goal is to split out the multi line events and send those VIA syslog.

Comment: So, you want the result to be a list of multi-line strings starting from `START--` until the next occurrence of `START--`?

Comment: @mklement0 I've updated my question with sample events. I plan to use regex to parse the events. I've already tested this regex and it works great. When I use get-content and then split with the regex is works. However, I'm trying to speed things up and use less computing resources.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Not exactly, the regex I've included accounts for finding the events. I'm just trying to improve performance at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch) statement with its `-File` option allows you to read a file's lines one by one, which keeps memory usage low and constant; option `-Regex` allows the branch handlers to be regular expressions.

```
$eventLines = ''
switch -Regex -File 'E:\Scripts\Logs\First1000' {
  '^START--' { # Note that the regex is case-INsensitive
    if ($eventLines) { 
        # send previous events' lines to syslog
    }
    # Current line is the start of a new event.
    $eventLines = $_
  }
  default { 
    # Event-interior line, append it.
    $eventLines += [Envirionment]::NewLine + $_
  }
}
# Process last event.
if ($eventLines) { 
    # send last event's lines to syslog
}
```

Alternatively, you could modify your `System.IO.File.ReadLines()` solution analogously and use an `if` statement with the string-literal `String.StartsWith()` method, which is faster than regex matching - however, in my informal tests the `switch` solutions still appears to be faster overall.

```
$eventLines = ''
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines('E:\Scripts\Logs\First1000')) {
  if ($line.StartsWith('START--')) {
    if ($eventLines) { 
        # send previous events' lines to syslog
    }
    # Current line is the start of a new event.
    $eventLines = $line
  } else {
    # Event-interior line, append it.
    $eventLines += [Environment]::NewLine + $line
  }
}
# Process last event.
if ($eventLines) { 
    # send last event's lines to syslog
}
```

Comment: @MrMr: Sorry to hear it. Unfortunately, I know nothing about syslog, but I encourage you ask a _new_ question (this one has a well-defined scope, as has the answer).